# Scrape dynamic web page with Python (input dates)

Tags: python, web-scraping, dynamic-pages

I'm trying to find a way to iterate through dates for a large period of time.
The site is: 
https://www.nnbulgaria.com/life-insurance/insurance-plans/investment-insurance-nn-pro/value-of-investment-unit
and there is a table in it with specific values for each date (begins on 06/01/2017, formated MM/DD/YYYY). With different date input the table changes, so I need to be able to loop through dates or a range of dates, and then extract the table data.
*(There is also a graph with all the values, but I can't find the dynamic content in the page source)*

The scraped data may be formatted or not (it's on separate td tags), but I can reshape it once it's downloaded.
So far I read about options with selenium, but I don't have Chrome installed, so I'm looking for other ways.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: `Selenium` works also with `Firefox`

Comment: if it use JavaScript to read data then first you should check in DevTools (in Chrome/Firefox, tab "Network") all requests to server and data in responses. Maybe you find your data in some response and then you can use this url to get data without `Selenium`. Oftern you can get it as JSON data which can easily converted to Python dictionary or list (using module `json`)

Comment: this page read some data from url https://www.nnbulgaria.com/Orchard.Nn/public/chartsUVData?chart-startdate=2004-06-01&chart-enddate=2020-04-23&value-per-share-type=LiPro

Comment: I'm setting my mind around the POST from

Comment: url in previous comment has dates `'chart-startdate'`, `'chart-enddate'` so you put dates directly in url and you don't need `'POST'`form.

Comment: @furas brilliant, thx! I'm curious how u dew it tho. :) This appears to have all the value in JSON format. But I'll cope. :)

Comment: I descirebed in answer how I found this url . Module `requests` can convert `JSON` data to Python dictionary/list - `data = response.json()` - and you have data without HTML scraping

Comment: Found it, thx! I had to reload the page and see the preview, plenty of stuff loading. Thx again!

Comment: there are buttons (filters) to display only some requests - button/filter `XHR` shows only `AJAX` requests.

Answer (score 1):

This page uses `JavaScript`/`AJAX` (`XHR`)

Using `DevTool` in `Chrome` of `Firefox` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) you can see all requests from `JavaScript` to server and all data in responses.

This way you can see it reads some data from url:

https://www.nnbulgaria.com/Orchard.Nn/public/chartsUVData?chart-startdate=2004-06-01&chart-enddate=2020-04-23&value-per-share-type=LiPro

and it gets `JSON` data which you can easily convert to Python dictionary.

In url you can see date `chart-startdate=` and `enddate=` so if you change dates then you should get different data - and you don't need to use `POST` form for this.

And it doesn't need to use `Selenium`

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.nnbulgaria.com/Orchard.Nn/public/chartsUVData'

params = {
    'chart-startdate': '2004-06-01',
    'chart-enddate': '2020-04-23',
    'value-per-share-type': 'LiPro',
}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = r.json()

print(data.keys())

for label, lowrisk, balanced in zip(data['labels'], data['dataLowRisk'], data['dataBalanced']):
    print(label, lowrisk, balanced)
```

Result

```
dict_keys(['labels', 'dataLowRisk', 'dataBalanced', 'dataAggressive', 'dataCommodities', 'dataMoneyMarket', 'dataUSEquities', 'dataGermanEquities', 'dataTechnologyCompaniesEquities'])

02.06.2017 1.0 0.99434
08.06.2017 0.9999 0.99387
14.06.2017 1.00092 0.99564
20.06.2017 1.0059 1.00039
26.06.2017 1.00375 0.99676
30.06.2017 0.99521 0.98354
06.07.2017 0.9932 0.98518
12.07.2017 0.99384 0.98384
18.07.2017 1.00056 0.9944
24.07.2017 0.99827 0.99075
```